# Envoy - failover to another control plane instance

Tags: envoyproxy

In our setting, Envoy consumes dynamic configuration from the control plane via GRPC. The control plane discovery is configured as STRICT_DNS:

```
- name: cplane
    connect_timeout: 5s
    type: STRICT_DNS
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: cplane
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: control-plane-fqdn
                port_value: 1234
```

Under the `control-plane-fqdn` DNS record we have multiple instances and Envoy connects to any one of them. The question is - what is the failover mechanism that Envoy uses? From my observations, failover to another instance (upon shutting down the one to which Envoy is connected) takes from 5 to 50 seconds. What is the reason for this spread and is it possible to make the failover time more deterministic?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found the answer. It is the exponential backoff mechanism defined here [1](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/0b10b055a6e1dbdd600f9a80f8b8d803bdd8ec9c/source/common/config/grpc_stream.h#L196). The parameter RetryMaxDelayMs is not configurable and is hard coded to 30 sec. Moreover, when the DNS has two IPs and one of them becomes unreachable, Envoy tries to reconnect to each IP in a round-robin manner with an exponential backoff between attempts. So, if the secondary IP is not ready to accept connection immediately then the exponential backoff may add another 30 - 40 sec until it reconnects.